# svn: 'proj' is already a working copy for a different URL

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control

I have tried to move a project currently located in  `https://svn.path.net/proj` to `https://svn.path.net/old/proj`  by following these steps:

- svn mkdir https://svn.path.net/proj
- svn move https://svn.path.net/proj https://svn.path.net/old/proj

I am able to see the move 'successfully' in my svn browser.

However, when I go to do `https://svn.path.net/old/proj /home/user/workspace/proj`, it'll give the error:

svn: 'proj' is already a working copy for a different URL

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing working copy for one location in a repository, and you want to switch it to point to another location in the same repository, then you need to use the `svn switch` command.